# How can I vertically align all my contents of my Table View Cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uistoryboard, tablecellrenderer

I want to make all the contents in my table cell vertical align center.

[image]

I want my content to render at the red line

[image]

---

I've tried

**via code**

```
func updateTableViewContentInset() {
    let viewHeight: CGFloat = view.frame.size.height
    let tableViewContentHeight: CGFloat = placesTable.contentSize.height
    let marginHeight: CGFloat = (viewHeight - tableViewContentHeight) / 2.0

    self.placesTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: marginHeight, left: 0, bottom:  -marginHeight, right: 0)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    updateTableViewContentInset()
}
```

[image]

---

I tried

[image]

I got

[image]

result

[image]

or even via the storyboard, but have not get the desired result that I am looking for yet.

**Any hints for me ?**

Comment: do you mean you want the cell content to be centered for each cell?

Comment: Did you add vertically centered constraint in your table view cell elements?

Comment: yes, I would like that. In `css` world, it called vertical align center.

Comment: @DionizB Do I have select each one and applied ? or select all 3 and then applied ?

Comment: Select all 3 and then apply center vertically in container

Comment: I did that and it does not come out good; :( Result : https://i.imgur.com/znrtK5t.png

Comment: No try Vertically in Container not Vertical Centers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly select the two elements in left and add them in vertical stack view like this: 
[image]

Then select the elements that you want to center inside your cell and apply Vertically in container.

[image]

For horizontal constraints between elements, select each element and add constraints like this:

[image]

Comment: Now that the elements are all centered you need to add horizontal constraints between them. Select each element, one by one, and add distances that you want from each other. And that should make it work :D

Comment: Result even more horrible now, I got this : https://i.imgur.com/WKlKls4.jpg

Comment: No, you need to do this one by one. And then you add constraints by clicking the square in the right of the button you clicked.

Comment: you said select `elements` you should say select `element one by one` - That part confuse me :p

Comment: I'll re-attempt

Comment: Read carefully, I said one by one :D

Comment: This is incorrect. Vertical center on the left labels will put them one on top the other

Comment: Yeah, but if you use stack Views it will work properly. Thanks for noticing I edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the top constraints of the labels and ctrl-drag from the left most label to contentView and select center vertically but note you need to implement `heightForRowAt` to give the correct height

Comment: is the cell content height dynamic or static

Comment: If you set the left two labels to center vertically they will be one on top of the other

Comment: I'm not listing all constraints sure there should be leading to first  with contentView , and  leading  of the other to be hooked to the first 's trailing, it's an illustration to the main fix

Answer (score 1):

If you want to center the content you can do the following in storyboard:

1. For the left side (two labels), add a vertical stack view and constraint it to content view's vertical center and a leading constraint to the content view.
2. In the stack view add your two labels, the stackview height/width will be set automatically (called intrinsic size, where the view calculates its size according to its content)
3. For the right side just add the labels and set a constraint to center vertically in the content view. add additional constraints to set them apart as they do now.

Comment: I will attempt those right now, and will update you.

Answer (score 0):

I have your cell laid out like this:

[image]

The address Top and Bottom labels are contained in a `UIStackView` with:

```
Alignment: Leading
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 4
```

- The stack view is constrained Leading to Leading Margin, and Vertically Centered
- The "miles" label is constrained Trailing to Trailing Margin, and Last Baseline to the "distance" label
- The "distance" label is constrained Trailing to "miles" Leading, with 8-pts for padding
- The "distance" label is also constrained Vertically Centered
- The StackView Trailing is constrained `>=` to "distance" Leading, with 8-pts for padding
- and finally, the "distance" label's Compression Resistance is set to `1000` to give it priority (so the address line may get truncated, but the distance value won't)

The result:

[image]

Here is the source of the xib file so you can inspect the layout if you run into any problems:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" rowHeight="70" id="luO-Wj-VHn" customClass="VertCenterCellXIB" customModule="SW4Temp" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="70"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="luO-Wj-VHn" id="bdC-Mi-Lfi">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="69.5"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" alignment="top" spacing="4" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9Ce-Dp-nkn">
                        <rect key="frame" x="16" y="15.5" width="119" height="39"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="39 Cosgrove St" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xch-Kp-Bi4">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="119" height="20.5"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="United States" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lYb-n3-8pd">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="24.5" width="77" height="14.5"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                    </stackView>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="7.8" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="i1h-WH-LQH">
                        <rect key="frame" x="260" y="9.5" width="53" height="50.5"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" weight="thin" pointSize="42"/>
                        <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.58980089430000004" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="miles" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="21q-Yj-LDN">
                        <rect key="frame" x="321" y="34.5" width="38" height="19.5"/>
                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                        <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.58980089430000004" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                    </label>
                </subviews>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstItem="i1h-WH-LQH" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="bdC-Mi-Lfi" secondAttribute="centerY" id="4vN-dI-N9v"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="9Ce-Dp-nkn" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="bdC-Mi-Lfi" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="595-Oi-wU4"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="9Ce-Dp-nkn" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="bdC-Mi-Lfi" secondAttribute="centerY" id="88e-Jn-rRu"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="21q-Yj-LDN" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="i1h-WH-LQH" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="LOe-Ph-3ve"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="i1h-WH-LQH" firstAttribute="leading" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="9Ce-Dp-nkn" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="XIw-PU-tKr"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="21q-Yj-LDN" firstAttribute="baseline" secondItem="i1h-WH-LQH" secondAttribute="baseline" id="aBn-DN-9wA"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="21q-Yj-LDN" secondAttribute="trailing" id="spV-CW-rmt"/>
                </constraints>
            </tableViewCellContentView>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="bottomAddressLabel" destination="lYb-n3-8pd" id="pcr-TF-F3g"/>
                <outlet property="distanceLabel" destination="i1h-WH-LQH" id="EcP-Xf-U6K"/>
                <outlet property="topAddressLabel" destination="xch-Kp-Bi4" id="vd5-YM-J10"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="35" y="-35"/>
        </tableViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```